# Cannot Find Module in the models folder

Tags: node.js

I have this basic structure `./api/controllers/authenticate.js` and `./api/models/authenticate.js` I want my controller to access the `authenticate.js` in the models folder as seen here.

*controllers/authenticate.js*

```
var app     =   require("express");
var router  =   app.Router();

var model   =   require("./api/models/authenticate.js");

router.get('/login',function(req,res){
    res.send(model.authenticate());
});

module.exports = router;
```

*models/authenticate.js*

```
var authenticate = function() {
    return "You should see this module";
}

module.exports = authenticate;
```

However I am getting a can not find the authenticate.js module in the models file. What am I missing?

Comment: var model   =   require("./../models/authenticate.js");

Comment: and res.send(model());

Comment: Also, I always used the path module for my absolute paths. `var absPath = path.join(__dirname, '../models/authenticate.js');`. In the end, it doesn't matter as long as it resolves, but it makes it easier to debug paths when you're missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

controllers/authenticate.js

```
var app     =   require("express");
var router  =   app.Router();

var model   =   require("../models/authenticate.js");

router.get('/login',function(req,res){
res.send(model.authenticate());
});

module.exports = router;
```

var model   =   require("./api/models/authenticate.js");  is wrong as you are already in /api/controllers/ directory and you are trying to access the models directory so you have to come one step back by using ../   then entering into models.  your case  trying to access a directory inside the models directory inside the controller directory

Comment: Explain your answer.[From review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10634473).

Comment: I understand the .. what does the . mean? From what I thought it references the root directory.

Comment: .. reference the parent directory and . reference the current directory.